# Injecting objects into forms

Tags: c#, winforms, dependency-injection

I'm developing a WinForms app, and i need to have some objects in every form, and i don't want to initialize each object on every form so, i created a base class:

```
public class FormBase : Form
{
    #region Properties

    public BusinessLogic.ChppManager ChppManager { get; protected set; }
    public BusinessLogic.DatabaseManager DatabaseManager { get; protected set; }
    public BusinessLogic.FileManager FileManager { get; protected set; }
    public BusinessLogic.RegistryManager RegistryManager { get; protected set; }

    #endregion Properties
}
```

And i pass each of those objects on the constructor. It works, but i wanted to know if there's an easier (standard) way to do this, without passing those parameters on every constructor call.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a dependency injection container like `Unity` to use constructor resolution of the constructor parameters, you would load the initialized objects into the Unity container and then use the `Resolve<T>()` method to resolve the dependencies at runtime meaning you don't have to specify them as parameters in your code - they would still need to be part of the constructor signature however.

If you abstract those Unity-resolved classes out to interfaces, it means that you could at a later stage change the underlying implementation so long as the interface remains the same.

Comment: in addition to your answer, I think it is worth mentioning that other IoC-Containers like Castle Windsor allow you to inject dependencies using properties like the OP wants to. This wouldn't require them to be part of the ctor's signature.

Comment: OK, i'll give Unity a look. Thanks.

Comment: Unity also performs property injection. However, you'll notice that he has set his setters to private so I'm guessing he doesn't want to allow accidental overwrite of those references, in which case, construction injection is the way forward.

Comment: I think your answer is confusing. You either use constructor injection, or you resolve your dependencies manually using `Resolve<T>()`. But not both. How are the dependencies part of you constructor signature of you are using `Resolve<T>()` ?

Comment: Unity injects dependencies in three ways: Annotated public properties,  via constructor parameters or method call parameters. The method which is used by Unity to construct a new object and resolve it's dependencies, using either injection-style, is the method `Resolve<T>()`. So yes, both. More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff664647(v=pandp.50).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The advised way is to *not* do this. Such base class with these dependencies is a code smell, because you are hiding the fact that the Form implementations use too many dependencies, which is an indication of violating the Single Responsibility Principle. Violations of the SRP often lead to harder to grasp, hard to maintain code.

Instead, prevent having a base class that takes these 'default' dependencies. If a class needs to use some service, inject it into the constructor. If a class needs too many dependencies, it's an indication of a SRP violation and you should investigate and refactor; for instance to [aggregate services](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/).